# Compass - include one value for another property

Tags: css, sass, compass

I want to include a value from another class - and use this for something different:

I have this class:

```
.sourceClass {
  color: red;
}
```

And I have this class:

```
.destinationClass {
  border-color: ###should be the color from .sourceClass => red
}
```

is this possible? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your post with "Sass". Are you using the Sass/SCSS preprocessor? If so, you'd declare and use a variable like this:

```
$myColor: red;

.sourceClass { color: $myColor; }
.destinationClass { border-color: $myColor; }
```

If you're not using Sass, you can read about [native CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) - which are currently working in Firefox and Chrome, but [not IE/Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

Lastly, there is a possible solution supported in all current browsers, which would be applicable depending on your DOM hierarchy: [currentColor](https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/).

If your `.destinationClass` is a child of `.sourceClass`, and therefore is inheriting `color: red`, you could simply use `border-color: currentColor` to take that color and use it as the border color.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you - the problem is, that I can not change the .sourceClass - so there ist no way use a variable.

Comment: @JörgWrase Hello, half a year later! Then the only solution would be the last part of my message - if `.destinationClass` is a child of `.sourceClass`, you can use `currentColor`.